# Display NSArray in the tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, nsarray

I'm going to display some data from NSArray in the tableViewCell.
Here is my NSArray format

```
 (
        {
        score = "480.0";
        uid = 2;
    },
        {
        score = "550.0";
        uid = 1;
    }
)
```

So, how to display for example score?
Here is m code, but it doesn't display it

```
var gamesRound: NSArray = []
let game = gamesRound[indexPath.row]
    //let user = users[Int(game.userId - 1)]
    cell.textLabel?.text = game as? String
    //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(String(Int(game.score))) PTS"
    //print(user.fullname!)
    return cell
```

Comment: try `cell.textLabel?.text = game["score"] as? String`

Comment: This method doesn't work, i've already try it :-(

Comment: Compiler is unable to indentify `game` as a dictionary, try `let game: [String: Any] = gameRound[indexPath.row] as! [String: Any]`

Comment: It doesn't work too

Comment: Can you show the code where you are initializing the `gamesRound`

Comment: is "game" an object instance of class Game ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your `gamesRound` variable to `Array` of `Dictionary` like this:
2. Put some value like this, in `viewDidLoad` (maybe):

   `var gamesRound = [[String: Any]]()`
3. To render value on cells of a `UITableView`

   `gamesRound = [["score": "480.0", "uid" = 2], ["score": "550.0", "uid": 1]]`

Some what like this:

```
let game = gamesRound[indexPath.row] as! [String: Any]
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(game["score"] as? Int ?? 0)"
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(game["uid"] as? Int ?? 0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the Array of dictionary so when you write `let dict = gamesRound[indexPath.row]` you will get the dictionary object and you can get the value by using the key because dictionary has the key value pair while the array has the indexing.

**Also, you can Declare array like this**

`var gamesRound: Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = []`

**So you can verify by printing the values step by step:**

```
print(gamesRound)
let dict = gamesRound[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
print(dict)
let score = dict["score"]
print(dict["score"])
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(score!)"
```

Comment: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: You have to get only dictionary if `gamesRound` an array

Comment: @GOODDUDE check my comment on your question. that might work

Comment: How you assign the value in `gamesRound`

Comment: See the answer again..!!

Comment: My array <var gamesRound: NSArray = []

Comment: `gamesRound` doesn't have any value. Debug it once using breakpoint.

Comment: Could you plz update the question where you were assigned the value to `gamesRound`

Comment: @GOODDUDE  I think you have to assign the value `gamesRound` seems like you are not assigning the array..

Comment: probably fix would be making your `gamesRound` variable to an Array of Dictionary, like this `var gamesRound = [[String: Any]]()`

Comment: It doesn't display in the tableViewCell. Here is print result   [["uid": 1, "score": 652.0], ["uid": 2, "score": 580.0]]

Comment: @GOODDUDE could you plz show the console by all the printing statement from mine answer?

Comment: Here is my console << [["uid": 2, "score": 580.0], ["uid": 1, "score": 653.0]] >>

Comment: And here `let dict = gamesRound[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
print(dict)`

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you have an `NSDictionary` in each position of you `NSArray`.

So, use this code to get the position that you want:

```
let game = gamesRound[indexPath.row]
```

Now the `game` is an `NSDictionary` and you only need to extract the information using the key that you want:

```
let uid = game["uid"]
let score = game["score"]
```

I hope my example helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
let gameRound : NSDictionary = yourArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

let strUid = gameRound["uid"]

cell.textLabel.text = strUid as? String
```